# Extending JPA entity at runtime to add one-to-many mapping

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have a requirement which forces me to extend an existing JPA entity at runtime to add one-to-many mapping. I came across ecliplselink wiki http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic. It seems very appealing.

It seems to be working in Java SE environment. 
Can I use the same approach in Java EE environment with glassfish 3.1.x server?

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Chir

Answer (score 1):

Also see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/External_Mappings

and,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Extensible_Entities

These should function in Glassfish.